# How to make a picture responsive that is on wordpress custom post type through HTML/CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am a newbie with in-depth work that includes Wordpress & Custom Type Post types. I have my Image correctly placed into wordpress and have successfully implemented the photo onto the "About Page". It works fine as far as desktop mode, but when I go responsive and bring it to tablet/mobile the picture states stationary and does not act responsive when translated to a Tablet/Mobile interface. I have been fiddling around with margins, applying my style syntax into different media queries but seem to get no result once bringing the responsive page down to Tablet or Mobile. Here are is my HTML Code & CSS Code that I have at this moment.

**HTML**

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: About
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="about" style="">
    <h1>Why?</h1>
</div>

<div class="about">
    Many may ask the question "Why". Questions such as; "Why is this website relevant?", "Why do I need to know this?" or "Why does this topic even matter?"
    Many of those questions can be anwsered in different ways, with different attitudes and opinions, yet the only importance this website offers is Knowledge.
    The access of clear and ordered catagories of famous people from the actors all the way up to our goverment officials whom represent us, the United States citizens, the opportunity for individuals that may have this disability to understand that it does not make you less from anyone else, and that it simply gives you the power to express who you are and reach milestones in your lifetime that many "ordinary" people don't.
</div>

<div class="about" style="">
    <h1>General Statistics</h1>
</div>

<div class="about">
    <img src="<?php the_field('data_graphic');?>"/>
</div>  

<main role="main" class="col-md-3">
<!-- section -->
    <section>
        <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <!-- article -->
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <br class="clear">
            </article>
            <!-- /article -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <!-- article -->
            <article>
                <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
            </article>
            <!-- /article -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        </section>
        <!-- /section -->
    </main>

    <?php //get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

**CSS**

.about img {
  max-width: 100%%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

If anyone could help me on figuring this responsive problem out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have two % in max-width it should be only one % like: max-width:100%;

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that last minute, and made a quick change, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do like this:

```
.about img{
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Note: This is for responsive images, i remove the position rules, because you can adjust yourself

Comment: Simple, it always get max width independently the browser size. If your browser/block gonna have 200px...the image will be 100% max of 200px.

Comment: Why are you using `height` and `display` and why did you remove `vertical-align` and `margin-left`?

Comment: `height:auto` -> proportional image; `display:block` -> as the name said, act like a block;  `margin-left: 150px` -> no reason

Comment: no need for the "!important" only use it when there is a real good reason

Comment: Yes...but is to avoid problems or misunderstandings testing the solution. I think is a good reason!

Answer (score 0):

You image needs to fill 100% of its container.

```
.about img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```